# C# - Run winform application on client PC that installed on server PC

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, client

I have a C# winform application with database. Database created on SQL Server Express 2014. Application can update, delete, insert records from database. I want to locate my application and its database on server computer and run it on client computer with shortcut. My connection string is

```
<add name="PRSoftDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PRSoftDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PRSoftDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PRSoftDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=PR;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The problem is I can't connect to database.
What I need, please help! 
Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to tell us your problem.

Comment: @rory.ap Problem is probably "it doesn't work" **;)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem! Enabled TCP\IP for SQL Server on server computer and changed connection string like below :

```
<add name="PRSoftDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PRSoftDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PRSoftDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PRSoftDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.105\sqlexpress;initial catalog=PR; user id = username; password=password; multipleactiveresultsets=True; application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

192.168.0.105 is server computer's IP adress. Now everthing works fine!

Answer (score 0):

instead

> data source=.\sqlexpress

use the ip addres of the server in connection string

> data source=ip\sqlexpress

and check ip logged user have access/rights to db, or  use

> integrated security=True

with a user that has right access/rights like

> User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;

check https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/